# Bootstrap 2.3.2 styles not being found/applied

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a basic Hello World page in Bootstrap, but the styles in the .css file are not being applied to the content on the page. In chrome dev tools, the .js and .css files are successfully loaded and can be looked through in-browser, but the styles are not applied to the element.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Alex Rules</title>
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="styelsheet" media="screen" type="text/css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<div id="postContent" class="row">
    <div class="span6 offset3">
        Hello World!
    </div>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a step that I'm missing?

Comment: Maybe your page is cached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your link tag it says `rel="styelsheet"` and it should say `rel="stylesheet"`.

Comment: You're a genius! And I'm blind.